# spark writeStream into kafka - Difference between awaitTermination() vs awaitAnyTermination()

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

As per official documentation, I was using below code segment to write into kafka topic, but it was not writing into kafka.

```
finalStream = final \
  .writeStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers",bootstrap_servers) \
  .option("topic",topic_name) \
  .option("checkpointLocation", check_point_location) \
  .start()

finalStream.awaitTermination()
```

But by using `awaitAnyTermination()` instead of `awaitTermination()`, writing into kafka works.

```
spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination()
```

Please suggest the reason behind this.

Answer (score 2):

> "Difference between awaitTermination() vs awaitAnyTermination()"

Citing the comments in the Source Code

[awaitTermination](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/streaming/StreamingQuery.scala#L104): "**Waits for the termination of this query**, either by `query.stop()` or by an exception. If the query has terminated with an exception, then the exception will be thrown. Otherwise, it returns whether the query has terminated or not within the `timeoutMs` milliseconds. If the query has terminated, then all subsequent calls to this method will either return `true` immediately (if the query was terminated by `stop()`), or throw the exception immediately (if the query has terminated with exception)."

[awaitAnyTermination](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/streaming/StreamingQueryManager.scala#L115): "**Wait until any of the queries on the associated SQLContext has terminated** since the creation of the context, or since `resetTerminated()` was called. If any query was terminated with an exception, then the exception will be thrown. If a query has terminated, then subsequent calls to `awaitAnyTermination()` will either   return immediately (if the query was terminated by `query.stop()`), or throw the exception immediately (if the query was terminated with exception). Use `resetTerminated()` to clear past terminations and wait for new terminations. In the case where multiple queries have terminated since `resetTermination()` was called, if any query has terminated with exception, then `awaitAnyTermination()` will throw any of the exception. For correctly documenting exceptions across multiple queries, users need to stop all of them after any of them terminates with exception, and then check the `query.exception()` for each query."